# Factor terms by kets

Tags: list-manipulation, symbolic, factorization

I have an expression that contains several kets with numerical factors. I would like to retrieve the individual kets and store each individually as a list element.

The expression is as follows:

```
-(1/2) (1/2 + mf) Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + 
 1/2 (Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(3 - mf) (5 + mf)] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] + 
    2 Sqrt[(4 - mf) (4 + mf)] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf])
```

However when I try to `Expand` the expression Mathematica gives me this:

```
1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(3 - mf) (5 + mf)] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] - 
 1/4 Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] - 1/2 mf Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + 
 Sqrt[(4 - mf) (4 + mf)] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf]
```

Notice that there are 2 identical kets there (`Ket[-(1/2),1/2+mf]`). Right now my workaround this problem is... bad. I expand the expression, then compare the Ket parts as strings and if they match, I join them together.

```
 templist = Cases[-(1/2) (1/2 + mf) Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + 
    1/2 (Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(3 - mf) (5 + mf)] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] + 
       2 Sqrt[(4 - mf) (4 + mf)] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf]) // Expand, 
  Times[_, Ket[__]]]
Table[If[ToString@(templist[[i]] /. 
       Times[_, Ket[a_, b_]] -> Ket[a, b]) == 
    ToString@(templist[[j]] /. 
       Times[_, Ket[a_, b_]] -> Ket[a, b]), {templist[[i]] = 
     templist[[i]] + templist[[j]]; templist[[j]] = 0;}], {i, 1, 
   Length[templist]}, {j, i + 1, Length[templist]}];
```

However there must be a better way to retrieve Kets from a sum than this.

Answer (score 2):

Janis, I think the following approaches might be easier. I am going to name your expanded expression for convenience:

```
expandedexpr = 
  1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(3 - mf) (5 + mf)] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] - 
   1/4 Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] - 1/2 mf Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + 
   Sqrt[(4 - mf) (4 + mf)] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf];
```

---

**Easiest of all** is to use `Simplify` on the expanded expression and let *Mathematica* do all the work for you:

```
Simplify[expandedexpr]

(*
1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[15 - 2 mf - mf^2] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] - 
1/4 (1 + 2 mf) Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + Sqrt[16 - mf^2] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf]
*)
```

---

It may be useful for future reference for you to see that you can easily **extract a list of Ket expressions** from the expanded expression you have using `Cases`, without transforming them to strings. This relies on the convenient fact that the parts you want have head `Ket`.

```
Cases[expandedexpr, _Ket, Infinity]

(* Out: 
{Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf], Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf], Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf], Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf]}
*)
```

As you mentioned, one of the `Ket` expressions is duplicated. You can then feed that list to `Collect` to have these expressions collected. In one step, this would look like the following:

```
Collect[expandedexpr, Cases[expandedexpr, _Ket, Infinity]]

(* Out: 
1/2 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[(3 - mf) (5 + mf)] Ket[-(3/2), 3/2 + mf] + 
(-(1/4) - mf/2) Ket[-(1/2), 1/2 + mf] + Sqrt[(4 - mf) (4 + mf)] Ket[1/2, -(1/2) + mf]
*)
```

---

You can check that the two approaches are ultimately equivalent:

```
Simplify[
 Simplify[expandedexpr] == Collect[expandedexpr, Cases[expandedexpr, _Ket, Infinity]]
]

(* Out: True *)
```